# Calculating a line integral for a conservative vector field

Tags: calculus, integration

**Question** Compute $\int \limits_{C} F\cdot dr$ for $F(x,y)=(y,x)$ and $C$ is the curve given by $r=1+\theta$ for $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$.

**My Attempt**

$F$ is conservative and a potential function is $f=xy$. First convert into polar coordinates, $f=r^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$

Start point: $(r, \theta) = (1,0)$

End point: $(r, \theta) = (1+2\pi,2\pi)$
Therefore by the properties of conservative vector fields:

$$f(b) - f(a) =  (1+2\pi)^2\sin(2\pi)\cos(2\pi) - (1)^2\sin(0)\cos(0) = 0 - 0 = 0. $$

Is this the correct method and answer?
Thank you!

Comment: It's the correct answer and the method is good.

Comment: I already pointed out where the mistake was!  in your deleted answer!

Comment: Yes, I've already corrected that mistake, is it correct now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally: if the field is conservative and the potential is the same in the endpoints of the curve, the integral will be zero. Let be $\gamma:[a,b]\longrightarrow\Bbb R^2$ a parametrization of $C$:
$$\int_C F\cdot dr = \int_C \nabla f\cdot dr = f(\gamma(b)) - f(\gamma(a)) = 0.$$

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, corrected. Thanks for pointing my mistake.